# zookeeper register >>Connection refused: no further information

Tags: zk

have you ever been in a situation where zookeeper starts up and connects normally, But when it's used, it throws a Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException, Java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information. The zoo.cfg file passed my check with no problem, I ran it locally. What is the cause of this.

Turn off the firewall and delete the log version information, and even let zk bypass sasl security mechanisms, but my zk version is 3.6.4, and the pom dependency in the project is 3.4x, I am not sure if it is due to version issues.These attempts have been ineffective!

Comment: Where are you getting the error?
Generally, enabling debug logs helps with these kinds of issues on both sides.

**Disclaimer**: I have no experience with zookeeper.